# Open windows directory through php

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a code where it uploads files to a dynamic folder. I want to echo the link of the dynamic folder in where the files are being saved for the user to view the file(s) in the directory. My code is as below :

```
     <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="Filename">
        <input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
            $myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
            $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
            $Filename=$_POST['Filename'];
            $structure = "Uploads/SystemConfiguration/$Filename";
            if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true))
            {
                die('Failed to create folders...');
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
            $name = $_FILES["my_file"]["name"][$i];
            $tmp_name=$_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"$structure/$name");
                ?>
                    <p>File #<?= $i+1 ?>:</p>
                    <p>
                        Name: <?= $myFile["name"][$i] ?><br>
                        Temporary file: <?= $myFile["tmp_name"][$i] ?><br>
                        Type: <?= $myFile["type"][$i] ?><br>
                        Size: <?= $myFile["size"][$i] ?><br>
                        Error: <?= $myFile["error"][$i] ?><br>
                        print "Your file upload was successful and can be seen/downloaded <a href='./uploads/systemconifguration/$Filename'>here</a>
                    </p>
                <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Even though I am giving href and specifying the windows directory path, it doesn't open. What is missing in the code? Appreciate any help :)

Comment: For one you need to have `$structure = "Uploads/SystemConfiguration/" . $Filename;` instead of `$structure = "Uploads/SystemConfiguration/$Filename";`

Comment: Is that to create the folders with $filename as the name? I can create folders and save files, but can't echo the link to the directory where the files are saved.

Comment: Alright, so the difference is that in one, you're literally looking for the path `"$filename"`, as in the name of the file is `"$filename"`. It doesn't matter if you have a variable `$filename = "lolol";`, if you put `$filename` in quotes it will always be `"$filename`" and not the value, `"lolol"`. To get the value and concat it in a string, you MUST do something like `$str = "first part " . $filename;` to make `$str == "first part lolol"`

Comment: Okay! That is done and I am getting the dynamic directory name, but it doesn't open. Is there a way I can open the windows directory? I've researched quite a bit and as per what I read there isn't a way you could do that. But just want to make sure before I do give up. I don't mind using javascript/jquery/ajax for this! Thanks :)